# Apache shows default index page instead of the page in virtualhost

Tags: php, apache

I tried to getting rid of xampp in favor of apache, php and mysql manually so I installed apache2 on my windows 10, and it works without any problems.

I change the path to be `C:/Server/Apache24` and change the default index page to `index.php` by typing `localhost/` in the address bar I can see the default page "It Works"

I created a virtual host for my web server:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/Server/Apache24/htdocs/test"
    ServerName test.com
</VirtualHost>
```

But the address `test.com` gives me the same default page and whenever I call any virtual host I'm getting the same default page

When I type `http://localhost/test/` it works correctly and gives me the project index page.

My settings in httpd.conf:

```
ServerRoot "c:/Server/Apache24"
ServerName localhost

DocumentRoot "c:/Server/Apache24/htdocs"
<Directory "c:/Server/Apache24/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.asp index.shtml index.html index.htm \
                   default.php default.pl default.cgi default.asp default.shtml default.html default.htm \
                   home.php home.pl home.cgi home.asp home.shtml home.html home.htm
</IfModule>

<Directory "c:/Server/Apache24/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Have you restarted Apache after you made the config change?

Comment: yes i restarted it many times .. also restarted the machine

Comment: Where, in what file, did you create the virtual host entry? If it was in `Apache24\conf\extra` did you also also remove the # in front of the `Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` entry in the main configuration file (`httpd.conf`)?

Comment: yes the # removed in this line

Comment: Your `IfModule dir_module` section is correct.  Check your hosts file upstream for any url rewrites or redirects, or if nothing there, remove everything from index.php downstream to make sure nothing going on there.